# How to add edit link within add to cart form in ubercart drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart

I need to add ***edit*** link within **add to cart** form in ubercart in Drupal 7.
I am using `hook_form_uc_cart_view_form_alter()` hook but not getting how to add ***edit*** link within this hook.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably confusing due to UC's reliance on TAPIr to render the cart items. Anyway, you can modify data inside in the `$form['items']` array to change the output of those elements. For example, if you wanted to add an edit link underneath the product description:

```
function MYMODULE_form_uc_cart_view_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  foreach($form['items'] as $key => $value) {
    //Check a TAPIr row for a product associated with an editable nid
    if(is_int($key) && isset($value['nid']['#value']) && isset($value['desc'])) {
      if(node_access('update', $value['#entity'], $user)) {
        $form['items'][$key]['desc']['#markup'] .= l('(EDIT)', 'node/'.$value['nid']['#value'].'/edit');
      }
    }
  }
```

There might be a cleaner way to do this, but I haven't thought about TAPIr in a while.